# Can amazon AWS guarantee lower bounce rates (or reduce bounce rates) at receiver servers?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently delivering around 200k emails per day with my local server.
I have logic in place to wait 0.5 seconds before sending each mail.

I'd like to eventually get to send more than a million emails in the next months (maybe 10 millions per day, let's say one year from now).

Currently, with my waiting strategy, this is not possible.

I'd like to know therefore if using the Amazon Simple Email Service, I could get lower bounce rates.

As for the mechanisms involved: If the bounce rates will indeed be lowered for AWS, could this be perhaps because it's whitelisted by a lot of email providers?

Comment: It seems like this would depend heavily on why you are getting bounces.  Any insights, there?

Comment: Currently I'm not getting bounces. I will expect however that as the traffic increases, I will begin to get bounces. I'm curious about whether AWS offers some throttling protection somehow. From what I see on their website, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/improve-deliverability.html they only  make reccomendations on how not to get bounces. So I don't really understand if SES would have any advantages over my own machine for this, since this is my only pain point.

Answer (score 1):

Bounce rate for bulk emails totally depends on how effectively you have maintained your subscribers email list to send out bulk emails AWS SES has nothing to do with the increase or decrease in the bounce rate.

For example:

In first go if you send out 100 emails using AWS SES out of which 10 subscribers marks the email as spam.

In second go if you send 100 emails to same subscribers using AWS SES you will get a bounce rate of 10%. So AWS SES will not have any effect on the bounce rate.

**Bounce Rate:**

In order to reduce the bounce rate using your bulk email service, all subscribers in the list should be properly double opted-in, which means that you should have sent those subscribers an email asking them to verify their email address (and their willingness to receive your emails). This action serves a dual purpose: a) you are eliminating any invalid email addresses that might have been entered; and b) making sure that the email recipients do in fact own that email account and do wish to receive your emails.

So even if at the start the bounce rate using AWS SES will be low if the subscribers list is not maintained properly.

This article is also a good to read regarding for a good strategy to keep the bounce rate down. [AWS SES and deliverability](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/deliverability-and-ses.html).